# How to formulate NDSolve[...] for a two-sector SIR model

Tags: differential-equations, code-review, code-request, modeling, code-generation

The following `Code` aims to simulate the employment effects of a pandemic, drawing on the conventional SIR model. I extended the SIR model with two economic sectors (denoted by i=1,2) and a non-economic population (denoted by i=0) to account for the infection in the entire population of a country. My main purpose is to describe the dynamics of infection across economic and non-economic parts of society. After finding the time path of the sectoral infection level, I will introduce it into a 2-sector model.

However, I am stuck with various mistakes in formulating this `NDSolve[...]`. I appreciate your suggestions for improvements for this `Code`.

```
ClearAll[NNf, pop, INF, sol];

NNf[1] = 666146;
NNf[2] = 1252935;
pop = 12000000;
β0 = 0.2;
β[1] = 0.1;
β[2] = 0.15;

INF[t_] := Total@Table[inf[i][t], {i, 0, 2}];

sol = Assuming[
   1 == Total@Table[sus[i][t - 1] + inf[i][t - 1], {i, 0, 2}],
NDSolve[
Flatten@{
  Table[{sus[0]'[t] == -β0*sus[0][t - 1]*(INF[t - 1]/pop),
    sus[i]'[
      t] == -β[i]*
       sus[i][t - 1]*(inf[i][t - 1]/NNf[i]) - β0*
       sus[i][t - 1]*(INF[t - 1]/pop),
    inf[0]'[
      t] == β0*sus[0][t - 1]*(INF[t - 1]/pop) - γ*
       inf[0][t - 1],
    inf[i]'[
      t] == β[i]*
       sus[i][t - 1]*(inf[i][t - 1]/NNf[i]) + β0*
       sus[i][t - 1]*(INF[t - 1]/pop) - γ*inf[i][t - 1],
    rec[i]'[t] == γ*INF[t - 1]}, {i, 2}],
  rec[0]'[t] == γ*INF[t - 1],
  inf[0][0] == 0.10,
  inf[1][0] == 0.05,
  inf[2][0] == 0.05,
  sus[0][0] == 0.50,
  sus[1][0] == 0.15,
  sus[2][0] == 0.15},
Flatten@Table[{sus[i], inf[i], rec[i]}, {i, 0, 2}], {t, 1, 100}]
];
```

Comment: It looks like you try to solve system of delay differential equations. For this you need to define functions `sus[i][t]` for $t<0$, not for $t=0$ only.

Comment: @Alex Trounev: For a simple delay DE, what is the difference between `Table[sus[i][t /; t <= 0] ==0.9,{i,0,2}]` and `Table[sus[i][0]==0.9, {i,0,2}]`?